# How to export multiple public certificate in one crt file

Tags: java, private, x509certificate, keystore, public

I have a keystore.jks file with multiple certificate including public and private key.
now i want to know how to export all public key certificate into new file all-public-cert.crt file.

This "all-public-cert.crt" file contain only certificate (public key only) . should not contain any private key in this file.

after this i would like to ready this "all-public-cert.crt" file via java code and validate public and private key using challenge response.

kindly guide me or suggest me some reference document or url.

Note : i am able to use any tool like openssl or keytool.

Thanks & Regards,
Gaurav Paliwal

Answer (score 1):

Normally a keystore i.e., your keystore.jks contains private keys and the corresponding X.509 certificates. But the X.509 certificates do NOT include a private key, as you falsely assumed:

```
I have a keystore.jks file with multiple certificate including public and private key

This "all-public-cert.crt" file contain only certificate (public key only) . should not contain any private key in this file.
```

This means that your X.509 certificates do only contain public key information, no private key information.

In order to fetch a certificate form your keystore (leaving the error handling aside):

```
String keystorePath = ....
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(keystorePath));
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(is, "keystorePassword".toCharArray());

Enumeration e = ks.aliases();
Set<Certificate> certs = new HashSet<Certificate>();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
  Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate((String) enumeration.nextElement());
  certs.add(cert);
}
```

Now you have all certificates in your `certs` Set. But why do you need to put them all into the `all-public-cert.crt`.

1.) First you cannot put multiple certificates in one file, and hope that the one file can be used the "normal" way (e.g. double click to open it, import it into other applications, ..). The file will be garbage and can only be read from e.g., your application

2.) Therefore the file extension should not be `.crt`, it should be `.myExportedCertificates` or something like that.

I think you just want to store the certificates on the file system in order to use them afterwards. In this case simply use this code (error handling is your job):

```
String pathToStoreTheCerts = ...
File path = new File(pathToStoreTheCerts);
OutputStream os = null;
for (X509Certificate cert : certs) {
  File certFile = new File(path, cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName() + ".crt");
  os = new FileOutputStream(certFile);
  os.write(cert.getEncoded());
  os.flush();
}
os.close();
```